# How can I set a Rigidbody component settings before adding the component to all the objects?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GenerateStairs : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject stairsPrefab;
    public float delay = 3;
    public int stairsNumber = 5;
    public Vector3 stairsStartPosition;
    public Vector3 stairSize;
    public Vector3 stairsSize;
    public float stepWidthFactor = 1f;
    public MoveObjects moveobjects;
    public bool addRigidbody = false;

    private Vector3 stairsPosition;
    private GameObject stairsParent;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        stairsParent = GameObject.Find("Stairs");
        StartCoroutine(BuildStairs());
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }

    private IEnumerator BuildStairs()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= stairsNumber; i++)
        {

            stairsPosition = new Vector3(
                    stairsStartPosition.x,
                    stairsStartPosition.y + (i * stairsSize.y),
                    stairsStartPosition.z + (i * stairsSize.y) * stepWidthFactor);

            GameObject stairs = Instantiate(
                    stairsPrefab,
                    stairsPosition,
                    Quaternion.identity);

            if(addRigidbody)
            {
                stairs.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
            }
            stairs.tag = "Stair";
            stairs.transform.parent = stairsParent.transform;
            stairs.transform.localScale = stairSize;

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        }

        moveobjects.Init();
    }
}
```

Before adding the rigidbody to each stair here:

```
stairs.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

I want first in the Start to set the rigidbody values settings using public variables like mass drag use gravity and other stuff of rigidbody then to add to each object the rigidbody with already the settings I did.

No if I'm adding the rigidbody to each object it will be with the default rigidbody settings I want to control this settings before adding the rigidbody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to control this settings **before** adding the rigidbody.

You can't because you can't because you cannot add existing component to a GameObject. The `AddComponent` function adds new instance of the Component to the GameObject.

Note that the `AddComponent` function adds the component then returns the instance it just added to the GameObject. You can modify that instance component it returned and that's what you should do.

The Rigidbody that holds the default settings:

```
public Rigidbody deafultSettings;
```

Add the Rigidbody component to your stairs GameObject then return the added component:

```
Rigidbody stairRb = stairs.AddComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

You can now modify the returned component or make a function to simplify that for you:

```
CopyRigidBodySettings(deafultSettings, stairRb);
```

The `CopyRigidBodySettings` function:

```
void CopyRigidBodySettings(Rigidbody destination, Rigidbody source)
{
    destination.useGravity = source.useGravity;
    destination.mass = source.mass;
    destination.drag = source.drag;
    destination.angularDrag = source.angularDrag;
}
```

---

Components are modified after adding them not before adding them. That shouldn't be a problem but if you don't like that, use a prefab. In fact, this is what prefabs are made for so that you can create a GameObject with default settings then re-use them. Create a prefab of your stairs with `Rigidbody` already attached to them then use the `Instantiate` function to instate the prefab. You can modify the prefab in the Editor or script before instantiating it.